# Algorithm for 0 and any other x

Tags: algorithm, math

I need to write an algorithm that takes a positive integer x. If integer x is 0, the algorithm returns 0. If it's any other number, the algorithm returns 1.

Here's the catch. I need to condense the algorithm into one equation. i.e. no conditionals. Basically, I need a single equation that equates to 0 if x is zero and 1 if x > 0.

EDIT: As per my comment below. I realize that I wasn't clear enough. I am entering the formula into a system that I don't have control over, hence they strange restrictions.

However, I learned a couple tricks that could be useful in the future!

Comment: By "no conditionals," do you also mean "no [ternary operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation)"?

Comment: This can also be easily achieved using some a combination of `abs`, `min` and `max`, in whatever language you're using.

Comment: Well, a ridiculous way of doing it would be `x/x` while catching divide-by-zero exceptions. (please don't do this)

Comment: @Geobits Or just rely on IEEE-754 behavior? `return (float)(x) / (float)(x) == ((float)(x) / (float)(x);`? (yay, that's horrible.)

Comment: `I need to write an algorithm that takes a positive integer x. If integer x is 0, the algorithm returns 0. If it's any other number, the algorithm returns 1.` Assuming you didn't misquote your homework problem, then this may be a test in how well you read the requirements. The answer is `int f(int x) { return 1; }` or the equivalent in whatever language you are using. Why? Because x is a "positive integer" - it's never 0.

Comment: Guys, it's not a homework problem, this is for my job :p. I wasn't really clear enough about my problem. I'm actually entering this formula into a program, not programming it.

Answer (score 6):

In C and C++, you can use this trick:

```
!!x
```

In those languages, !x evaluates to 1 if x is zero and 0 otherwise. Therefore, !!x evaluates to 1 if x is nonzero and 0 otherwise.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Try `return (int)(x > 0)`

In every programming language I know, `(int)(TRUE) == 1` and `(int)(FALSE) == 0`

Comment: Agreed this will work, but does it break the "no conditional" rule?

Comment: @Geobits I think the requirement was "no conditional in the language", and not "no conditional in the assembly or the implementation of the interpreter".

Comment: @H2CO3 Probably, just hoping the OP could clarify is all.

Comment: @Geobits That would definitely be the cleanest solution.

Comment: I don't know about modern languages, but I did work with a language years ago in which true was -1 (actually 0xFFFF--it was a 16-bit machine). In addition, older C compilers didn't define true and false. true was "non-zero". Such a compiler could have turned your code into `return x;` Finally, not all languages support casting a Boolean result to an integer (C# being such a language).

Comment: @JimMischel That's not a matter of the compiler. C has no true boolean data type (not even `_Bool` behaves like one).

Comment: @H2CO3: Does the C standard say that `(int)(x > 0)` will result in `1` (assuming that `x > 0`), or that the result will be "non-zero"?

Comment: @JimMischel It's guaranteed to be one.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming 32-bit integers:

```
int negX = -x;
return negX >> 31;
```

Negating x puts a 1 in the highest bit. Shifting right by 31 places moves that 1 to the lowest bit, and fills with 0s.  This does nothing to a 0, but converts all positive integers to 1.

This is basically the [sign](http://bits.stephan-brumme.com/sign.html) function, but since you specified a positive integer input, you can drop the part that converts negative numbers to -1.

Comment: +1. Or, to make it a one-liner: `return (-x) >> 31;` Won't work with unsigned, though.

Answer (score 1):

Since virtually every system I know of uses IEEE-754 representation for floating-point numbers, you could just rely on its behavior (namely, that `0.0 / 0.0` is `NaN`, and `NaN != NaN`). Pseudo-C (-Java, ...) follows:

```
float oneOrNAN = (float)(x) / (float)(x);
return oneOrNAN == oneOrNAN;
```

Answer (score 0):

Like I said, I wasn't clear enough in my problem description. When I said equation, I meant a purely algebraic equation.

I did find an acceptable solution: Y = X/(X - .001)

If it's zero you get 0/ -.001 which is just 0. Any other number, you get 5/4.999 which is close enough to 1 for my particular situation.

However, this is interesting:

```
!!x
```

Thanks for the tip!